# how to determine the equation of a 2d shape given x and y coordinates?

Tags: calculus

Im trying to get my program to match a particular shape anywhere on screen. It will always be the same size regardless of where it is. I could play with the coordinates but I dont think it's the best way of doing things.

How can I turn the coordinates into an equation that I can match with shapes seen?

I looked into polynomial interpolation but I know all of the points along the curve.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks. 
BK

Comment: There are uncountably many 2D shapes, and not all have equations.  Is this a particular shape? A circle? An ellipse? Or just any possible shape?

Answer (score 0):

If you know three points on the circle $A$, $B$ and $C$, you can easily found the equation of the circle. Here the graph:

[image]

From this, draw the axis of the segments $AB$ and $CD$. Mark as $P$ the intersection of the two lines:

[image]

The point $P$ is the centre of the circunference that contains $A$, $B$, $C$:

[image]

Setting for example $O(0,0)$ in the lower left angle of the screen you can easily find the equation of the circle and draw it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for an answer; I was looking for away to test curve similarity. I found [Fréchet distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance)

Thanks.